# Getting the IDs and the attributes of two adjacent nodes in OrientDB

Tags: orientdb, graph-traversal, nosql

I am trying to perform a join between the vertices in the Test1 class and the ones that are adjacent to them, but I'm getting a parsing error since the keyword `join` is not allowed. I am trying to show both IDs of the source and destination nodes along the relation `Path`, and to get the names of the two vertices

```
select @rid as P, name as N from Test1 join 
   (select @rid as R, name as M from (select expand(out('Path')) from Test1)) 
   on t.P=u.R
```

Update:

I tried the following solution, but all the elements are packed in a collection, while in my case I would like to perform a cartesian product:

```
select @rid, out('Path').@rid as rid2, name, out('Path').name as name2 from Test1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select in.name as name1, out.name as name2, in.@rid as id1, out.@rid as id2 from Path
```

Answer (score 1):

I have this simple dataset:

[image]

a simple way to retrieve all the elements of two adjacent nodes could be the usage of the `bothV()`function.

**Query:**

```
SELECT expand(bothV('TestClassEdge')) FROM TestClassEdge
```

**Output:**

[image]

Hope it helps